# Extract longest flow path in ArcGIS pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, hydrology, slope

I did calculate Hydrology with **Spatial Analysis tools==> Hydrology** and now, I have streams and Watershed. In each watershed, I need to extract the longest Flow as a polyline for calculate slope. What should I do?
[image]